# Parsing JSON and get the values

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I have som trouble parsing my JSON. Im wondering how I can get hold of the value1 and value2 in the "sel" object (see JSON below). I've been doing like this:

```
 SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
 NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
 NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


 NSMutableDictionary *json = [jsonParser objectWithString: json_string];

    //NSLog(@"%@", json);

    for(NSDictionary *dict in [json valueForKey:@"sel"])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [dict objectForKey: @"value1"]);
    }
```

This gives me an error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88314c0'
```

How do i reach value1 and value2?
My JSON looks like this:

```
{
        content =  {
                details = {
                    desc = "lorem";
                    name = lorem;
                    options = {
                        name = lorem;
                    };
                };
            };
        };
        sel =     {
            other =         (
            );
           content =         {
                id = 95;
                "date" = "2013";
                price = 100;
            };
            value1 = 100;
            value2 = 100;
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please spend a little time searching for an answer (or trying to figure it out yourself) before asking here.  We're not here to write your code for you.

Comment: I have been spending time trying to solve it. But my app crashes when im trying to get objectForKey ["value1"] in my dictionary.

Comment: show your code to parse JSON.

Comment: SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [[SBJsonParser alloc] init];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]];
    NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *json_string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    
    NSMutableDictionary *json = [jsonParser objectWithString: json_string];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", json);
    
    for(NSDictionary *dict in [json valueForKey:@"sel.value1"])
    {
        NSLog(@"dict %@", dict);

Comment: Edit your question to show the code.  No, on second thought, don't.  Go look at other examples some more, and don't merely copy them, but *understand* them.

Comment: (There is no key "sel.value1" in the above JSON.)

Comment: Yeah sorry, I've updated my question. Just asking for some guide in the right direction or some help. I do understand what ive been doing up til' now.

Comment: Do you understand how to read an NSLog dump?  `()` brackets arrays and `{}` brackets dictionaries.  There is a 1:1 relationship between JSON and Objective-C arrays and between JSON "objects" and Objective-C dictionaries.  (And definitely learn the [JSON syntax](http://json.org).)

Comment: (Your main problem with your original code above is that you shouldn't iterate through a dictionary.  That has you looking in every element of "sel" for a dictionary containing "value1", and there is no such dictionary, plus some elements (such as "value1") are not dictionaries and will choke on the objectForKey operation.)

Comment: Sorry but why? "sel" with {} brackets is a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, sel is a dictionary, containing an array, a dictionary, and two strings.  You try to treat all 4 items like dictionaries.

Comment: (The idea  behind a dictionary is that you don't have to iterate through it to find something.)